# Como agrupar dados em um array, fazendo um único objeto | MONGO + NODE

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Eu gostaria de buscar dados do usuário junto com seus portfólios vinculados em uma matriz, no entanto, está trazendo como dois arrays.
E dentro de cada carteira tem um array de "entrances" aonde gostaria de trazer o dado referenciado nela do type_sport dentro de cada entrada.

**MONGO DB + NODE.JS**

Eu tenho 4 coleções

**PEOPLE**

```
"_id" : ObjectId("5d27b7ba5455a11eacdf164d"), 
"name" : {
     "first" : "Alexssander ", 
     "last" : "Leal"
}, 
"user" : {
     "active" : true, 
     "admin" : false, 
     "email" : "alex.leal.pls@gmail.com", 
     "password" : "123456"
},
```

**WALLETS** - Com duas carteiras relacionadas no usuário

```
"_id" : ObjectId("5d27fbf95a298d4470416f33"), 
"members" : [
     {
         "creator" : true, 
         "people_id" : ObjectId("5d27b7ba5455a11eacdf164d")
     }
 ], 
 "name" : "Fundo de investimentos", 
 "type_coins_id" : ObjectId("5d1ebbb44a2b012e343ff48c"),
 "entrances" : [
     {
          "event" : "Arsenal x Manchester United",
          "stake" : 75,
          "type_sport" : ObjectId("5d1ebbb44a2b012e343ff568")
     },
     {
          "event" : "Bayer x Liverpool",
          "stake" : 75,
          "type_sport" : ObjectId("5d1ebbb44a2b012e343ff568")
     }
 ]
```

______________________________________________________________________________-

```
"_id" : ObjectId("5d280149b1e77444a013c86b"), 
 "members" : [
     {
         "creator" : true, 
         "people_id" : ObjectId("5d27b7ba5455a11eacdf164d")
     }
 ], 
 "name" : "Bolsa esportiva", 
 "type_coins_id" : ObjectId("5d1ebbb44a2b012e343ff48c"), 
 "entrances" : [
     {
          "event" : "Barcelona x Real Madrid",
          "stake" : 50,
          "type_sport" : ObjectId("5d1ebbb44a2b012e343ff568")
     },
     {
          "event" : "Santos x Flamengo",
          "stake" : 115,
          "type_sport" : ObjectId("5d1ebbb44a2b012e343ff568")
     }
 ]
```

**TYPE_COINS**

```
"_id" : ObjectId("5d1ebbb44a2b012e343ff48c"), 
"name" : "Real", 
"abbreviation" : "BRL",
```

**TYPE_SPORTS**

```
 "_id" : ObjectId("5d1ebbb44a2b012e343ff568"),
 "name" : "Futebol"
```

**MEU CÓDIGO DA QUERY**

```
let pipeline = [{
    $lookup: {
        from: 'wallets',
        localField: '_id',
        foreignField: 'members.people_id',
        as: 'wallets'
    },
}, {
    $unwind: { path: '$wallets' }
}, {
    $lookup: {
        from: 'type_coins',
        localField: 'wallets.type_coins_id',
        foreignField: '_id',
        as: 'wallets.type_coin'
    }
}, {
    $unwind: { path: '$wallets.type_coin'}
}];
```

No entanto, estão trazendo um array de usuário duplicado, alterando apenas a carteira obj de cada posição e duplicando registros de acordo com a quantidade de "entrances" dentro de cada carteira

**RESULTADO ESPERADO**

```
"_id" : ObjectId("5d27b7ba5455a11eacdf164d"), 
"name" : {
     "first" : "Alexssander ", 
     "last" : "Leal"
 }, 
 "user" : {
     "active" : true, 
     "admin" : false, 
     "email" : "alex.leal.pls@gmail.com", 
     "password" : "123456"
 }, 
 wallets: [{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5d27fbf95a298d4470416f33"), 
    "members" : [{
         "creator" : true, 
         "people_id" : ObjectId("5d27b7ba5455a11eacdf164d")
     }], 
     "name" : "Wallet 1", 
     "type_coins_id" : {
         "_id" : ObjectId("5d1ebbb44a2b012e343ff48c"), 
         "name" : "Real", 
         "abbreviation" : "BRL", 
     }, 
     "entrances" : [{
          "event" : "Arsenal x Manchester United",
          "stake" : 75,
          "type_sport" : {
               "_id" : ObjectId("5d1ebbb44a2b012e343ff568"),
               "name" : "Futebol"
          }
     },
     {
          "event" : "Bayer x Liverpool",
          "stake" : 75,
          "type_sport" : {
               "_id" : ObjectId("5d1ebbb44a2b012e343ff568"),
               "name" : "Futebol"
          }
     }]
},
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5d280149b1e77444a013c86b"), 
    "members" : [{
         "creator" : true, 
         "people_id" : ObjectId("5d27b7ba5455a11eacdf164d")
     }], 
     "name" : "Wallet 2", 
     "type_coins_id" : {
         "_id" : ObjectId("5d1ebbb44a2b012e343ff48c"), 
         "name" : "Real", 
         "abbreviation" : "BRL", 
     },
     "entrances" : [{
          "event" : "Barcelona x Real Madrid",
          "stake" : 50,
          "type_sport" : {
               "_id" : ObjectId("5d1ebbb44a2b012e343ff568"),
               "name" : "Futebol"
          }
     },
     {
          "event" : "Santos x Flamengo",
          "stake" : 115,
          "type_sport" : {
               "_id" : ObjectId("5d1ebbb44a2b012e343ff568"),
               "name" : "Futebol"
          }
     }] 
}]
```

Answer (score 2):

[manual/reference do pipeline](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.aggregate/#db.collection.aggregate)

Espero que ajude oque fiz:

```
db.people.aggregate([{
$lookup: {
    from: 'wallets',
    let: { walletsID: '$_id' },
    pipeline: [
        {
            $match: {
                $expr: {
                    $in: [ '$$walletsID', '$members.people_id' ],
                }
            }
        },
        {
            $lookup: {
                from: 'type_coins',
                localField: 'type_coins_id',
                foreignField: '_id',
                as: 'type_coin'
            }
        }, 
       { $unwind: { 'path': '$entrances', preserveNullAndEmptyArrays': true } },
        {
            $lookup: {
                from: 'type_sports',
                localField: 'entrances.type_sport',
                foreignField: '_id',
                as: 'entrances.type_sport'
            }
        }, 
        { $unwind: { 'path': '$entrances.type_sport', 'preserveNullAndEmptyArrays': true } },
        {
            $group: { 
                _id: "$_id",
                name:{$first: "$name"},
                members:{$first: "$members"},
                type_coin:{$first: "$type_coin"},
                entrances:{$addToSet: "$entrances"}
            }
        },
        { $unwind: { 'path': '$type_coin', 'preserveNullAndEmptyArrays': true } },
    ],
    as: 'wallets'
}}])
```

Resultado:

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("5d27b7ba5455a11eacdf164d"),
"name" : {
    "first" : "Alexssander ",
    "last" : "Leal"
},
"user" : {
    "active" : true,
    "admin" : false,
    "email" : "alex.leal.pls@gmail.com",
    "password" : "123456"
},
"wallets" : [
    {
        "_id" : ObjectId("5d280149b1e77444a013c86b"),
        "name" : "Bolsa esportiva",
        "members" : [
            {
                "creator" : true,
                "people_id" : ObjectId("5d27b7ba5455a11eacdf164d")
            }
        ],
        "type_coin" : {
            "_id" : ObjectId("5d1ebbb44a2b012e343ff48c"),
            "name" : "Real",
            "abbreviation" : "BRL"
        },
        "entrances" : [
            {
                "event" : "Santos x Flamengo",
                "stake" : 115,
                "type_sport" : {
                    "_id" : ObjectId("5d1ebbb44a2b012e343ff568"),
                    "name" : "Futebol"
                }
            },
            {
                "event" : "Barcelona x Real Madrid",
                "stake" : 50,
                "type_sport" : {
                    "_id" : ObjectId("5d1ebbb44a2b012e343ff568"),
                    "name" : "Futebol"
                }
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "_id" : ObjectId("5d27fbf95a298d4470416f33"),
        "name" : "Fundo de investimentos",
        "members" : [
            {
                "creator" : true,
                "people_id" : ObjectId("5d27b7ba5455a11eacdf164d")
            }
        ],
        "type_coin" : {
            "_id" : ObjectId("5d1ebbb44a2b012e343ff48c"),
            "name" : "Real",
            "abbreviation" : "BRL"
        },
        "entrances" : [
            {
                "event" : "Bayer x Liverpool",
                "stake" : 75,
                "type_sport" : {
                    "_id" : ObjectId("5d1ebbb44a2b012e343ff568"),
                    "name" : "Futebol"
                }
            },
            {
                "event" : "Arsenal x Manchester United",
                "stake" : 75,
                "type_sport" : {
                    "_id" : ObjectId("5d1ebbb44a2b012e343ff568"),
                    "name" : "Futebol"
                }
            }
        ]
    }
]}
```

Comment: Show, funcionou perfeitamente, muito obrigado!
Agora eu tenho um outro problema, talvez possa me ajudar também..
Tenho um array dentro de cada 'wallet' que se chama 'entrances'
e dentro de cada entrada tem um id representando qual esporte que corresponde aquela entrada, e gostaria de pegar na coleção de 'type_sports' os dados do esporte de cada entrada.

Comment: Edita o post e add a outras collection ai

Comment: Prontinho, editei com o que estou com duvida acima haha, muito obrigado pela ajuda e atenção :D

Comment: Veja ai se ajuda ..isso ai